# Среднее значение выбранных значений SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть запрос, выбирающий 2 значение из столбца:
`SELECT delay FROM firm1 ORDER BY delay LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2`

Все работает и возвращает 2 строки, но как только пытаюсь найти `AVG` или применить любую другую функцию, то запрос вообще ничего не возвращает (0 строк)
`SELECT AVG(delay) FROM firm1 ORDER BY delay LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2`

Где я не прав?

Comment: Запрос возвращает 1 строку, а у вас стоит OFFSET 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Где я не прав?

В том, что LIMIT применяется ПОСЛЕ вычисления AVG(). Из-за отсутствия GROUP BY среднее значение - ОДНО. И просить два, начиная со второго - это заведомо ничего не получить.

Решение - подзапрос с LIMIT и вычисление AVG dj внешнем запросе.